# How to prove Markov Chain formula?

Tags: probability, markov-process, dice

I saw an question about how often should I roll a 6-face dice to get every number at least once.

I have read a lot of interesting answers but one of them caught my attention. It is one which imples Markov Chain.

Acording to the author

> ThePawn has the right idea to attack the problem with a recurrence
>   relationship. Consider a Markov chain with states ${0,…,6}$
>   corresponding to the count of the number of distinct dice rolls that
>   have happened. State 0 is the start state, and state 6 is the finish
>   state. Then, the probability of transition from state $i$ to itself is
>   $\frac{i}{6}$.  The probability of transition from state $i$ to state
>   $i+1$ is $\frac{6-i}{6}$. Therefore the hitting time of the finish state
>   is
>
> $$\sum_{i=0}^5 \frac{6}{6-i} = 14.7 $$

I would like to know which steps with more details that I need to develop in order to prove that summation formula.

What if I change the dice for a 8-faces dice or even if I put 2 6-dices rolling at the same time?

Thank you, guys!
Luis P.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28905/expected-time-to-roll-all-1-through-6-on-a-die/28906#28906

Answer (score 4):

The expected hitting time is equal to the amount of time it takes to get from 0 to 6. At every jump of the Markov chain, you can either remain at the same state, i.e. you've thrown a number you already got before, or jump to the next state, meaning that you've collected a new number. Thus if $\tau$ is the total time it takes to get from 0 to 6 and $\tau_i$ is the time it took to get from $i$ to $i+1$, you want to calculate:

$$E[\tau]=E[\sum_{i=0}^{5}\tau_i]=\sum_{i=0}^5E[\tau_i],$$

by linearity of expectation.

Jumping from i to i+1 has has expected time:

$$E[\tau_i]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k(i/6)^k (1-i/6),$$

i.e. the expected value of a geometric distribution with success probability $p=1-i/6$, which has expected value $6/(6-i)$. This is how you arrive at:

$$E[\tau]=\sum_{i=0}^5\frac{6}{6-i}$$

The generalized form of this problem is known as the [coupon-collector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Comment: Beautiful! XXX Alex R.